# Flask Appbuilder - reduce decimals from created_on, changed_on

Tags: datetime, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

Is there a way to reduce the number of decimals from flask appbuilder's created_on, created_by columns?

I have tried (views.py):

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
formatters_columns = {"created_on": lambda x: x.isoformat(),
                      "changed_on": lambda x: x.isoformat(),
                      }
show_fieldsets = [created_on, changed_on]
```

This does not affect the way it is being displayed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```py
    formatters_columns = {
        'created_on': lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        'changed_on': lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}
```